# Assigning value to a property of a readonly object

Tags: ios, objective-c, readonly

I have 2 classes as per below:

***Class ModelA.h***

```
@interface ModelA : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayA;
@end
```

***Class ControllerA.m***

```
@interface ControllerA()
    @ property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) ModelA *modelProperty;
@end

@implementation ControllerA

- (void)someMethod:(NSArray *)sampleArray
{
    self.modelProperty.arrayA = sampleArray;
}
```

If I try to assign something to self.modelProperty, I get a build error which says I cannot since its a readonly property. But I assign something to its property it XCode doesn't give any error i.e. `self.modelProperty.arrayA = sampleArray` just builds fine. However when I debug through it and print `self.modelProperty.arrayA` I get nil even though sampleArray has data in it.

***Question:*** Is it possible to assign values to a property of a readonly object?

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly fine. However, you will see the result you are getting if `self.modelProperty` is `nil`. Make sure `modelProperty` has a value. FYI, it's kind of unusual to make a private property read-only. Normally you would make the public property read-only and then in the class extension you would make it readwrite so the class can make use of it.

Comment: Yup you all are right. I assigned something to modelProperty and works. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to assign values to a property of a readonly object?

Er, sort of. The language you used is slightly confusing. It isn't a *readonly object*; it's a *readonly property*. And it is possible to assign values to the object stored in a readonly property.

`readonly` just means that you can't *set* that property -- there is no `setModelProperty:` setter method.

It *does not* mean that the target of the object is immutable. It's not analogous to `const`. All it means is that you can't set the property.

The reason you're seeing `nil` is that *any message sent to `nil` returns `nil`*.

```
self.modelProperty.arrayA
```

Is the same as:

```
[[self modelProperty] arrayA]
```

If `modelProperty` is `nil` (which it is, from the code you've shown), this is the same as:

```
[nil arrayA]
```

Which returns `nil` -- in the same way that `[nil anyMethod]` returns `nil`.

---

Final note: you have `copy` set as the memory policy for the `modelProperty` property, but the `ModalA` class doesn't appear implement the `NSCopying` protocol. Are you sure you don't want `strong`?

Comment: Yup I want it to be copy. I will be implementing the NSCopying protocol. Thanks for explaining the readonly property. After assigning something to modelProperty this works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try: `_modelProperty = sampleArray`